# C# Moq - Cannot convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>

Tags: c#, inheritance, moq

In my unit test I am trying to setup a method to return a List when the actual method expects the return type to me a List. However I am getting this error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FSVendorRepository.AccountingManagement.Models.StatementDetail.RegionalStatementDetailItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FSVendorRepository.AccountingManagement.Models.StatementDetail.Base.StatementDetail>'
```

Which tells me I cannot mock my function to return a List.

Here is the code:

Base class:

```
namespace FSVendorRepository.AccountingManagement.Models.StatementDetail.Base {
    public abstract class StatementDetail {
              //Props
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
namespace FSVendorRepository.AccountingManagement.Models.StatementDetail {
    public class RegionalStatementDetailItem : Base.StatementDetail {
              //Props
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
namespace FSVendorRepository.AccountingManagement {
    public interface IAccountingManager {
        List<StatementDetail> ReturnDerivedListTest();
        StatementDetail ReturnDerivedClassTest();

    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
 public async Task ReturnStatementDetails_UserIsMasterSubRepAndIsExporting_CorrectRegionalStatementDetailsClassReturned() {
            var regionalItem = new RegionalStatementDetailItem();
            var liRegionalItems = new List<RegionalStatementDetailItem>();

            _iMockAccountingManager.Setup(x => x.ReturnDerivedListTest()).Returns(liRegionalItems); //compile time exception
            _iMockAccountingManager.Setup(x => x.ReturnDerivedClassTest()).Returns(regionalItem); //passes
}
```

I'm doubly confused when i created a method which returns a single instance of the base class and substituted it with the derived class and it worked.

Why doesn't think work?

Comment: read about covariance and contravariance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: Why you can't ?

Because, if you return a List<DerivedClass>, then this list must receive only DerivedClass. But a List<BaseClass> could also receive OtherDerivedClass .

So you can do *less* things with List<DerivedClass> compared to List<BaseClass> 
(But you can do *more* things with DerivedClass compared to BaseClass)

That's why the conversion can't be made simply by the compiler this way. These things are called covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `List<DerivedClass>` does not derive from `List<BaseClass>` and the fact that the `T` inside does is irrelevent when looking at it from that perspective.

What you're looking for is Covariance. There's MSDN documentation on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: `it can't magically know that the T inside does.` Of course both the compiler as well as the runtime know. That is not the problem. You cannot treat a List<Dog> like a List<LivingThing>, because otherwise you could add flowers to your list of dogs, which of course doesn't make much sense (unless flowers are dogs...), hence the error...

Comment: Edited for clarity